# How to change number of posts shown on homepage vs other pages?

Tags: posts, functions

I tried using this function but my homepage (which is the latest posts, not static) shows 5 posts -- the else.

```
function limit_posts_per_page() {
if ( is_front_page() || is_home() )
    return 1; 
else 
    return 5;   
}

add_filter('pre_option_posts_per_page', 'limit_posts_per_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your new modified code, neither can I find an exact use case which I have done previously, but as I already said, you should be using `pre_get_posts` to set your desired amount of posts on the home page.

Before I do, just a pro tip which will safe you many headaches due to debugging, use proper old school syntax, the curly bracket (*`{}`*). I do not know of code editors that support your syntax, which makes debugging a nightmare. Curly brackets are supported by all. So avoid using

```
if ( 'something' )
   // Do what you need to do
else
    // Do something else
```

and avoid using

```
if ( 'something' ) :
   // Do what you need to do
else :
    // Do something else
endif;
```

and rather use

```
if ( 'something' ) {
   // Do what you need to do
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

To come back to the issue, you can try

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 ); // Remove post if you only need page
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the great reminder, Peter. I did notice that code was missing curly brackets and thought maybe that was the problem, but adding them didn't work. I used pre_get_posts and also the action you posted but neither worked. It occurred to me that I'm using JetPack's Infinite Scroll, but it's set to click so that shouldn't be affecting it. I'm stuck unfortunately.

Comment: The missing curly brackets in context of your code is completely 100% valid PHP, it is just that I do not like it as it is not debuggable ;-). I have tested your code, and on my side it works, even the code I have posted works. I'm not familiar with Jetpack, so I cannot say if that is your issue. Are you by any means using a custom query or `query_posts` somewhere. Something else is making the code not to work. Turn debugging on and check for obvious errors

Comment: You're right -- it works for me if I turn off Infinite Scroll. At least I know that's the problem now. Thank you!